# Splitting output power of a PFC stage to three flyback converters

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, boost, flyback, buck-boost, power-factor-correction

I want to design three flyback converters whose input is taken from a single power factor correction circuit based on boost converter topology. The PFC stage delivers 200 W (400 V, 0.5 A), and I want three flyback converters one with an output of 150 W (200 V, 0.75 A), another of 25 W (25 V, 1 A) and another of 5 W (12 V, 0.6 A). How can I achieve this, with stable outputs from all converters?

Comment: You can just connect all three converters to the output of your PFC. Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: Why would you not have one flyback converter with multiple outputs like the average lcd TV?

Comment: @Jonathan S. What will be the total efficiency?

Comment: @Kartman I want to have stable output for all the three converters

Comment: Why wouldn’t it be stable if your PFC has enough power for all your downstream converter?

Comment: @winny. Thanks for the eye opener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *The PFC stage delivers 200W(400V,0.5A), and I want three flyback
> converters one with an output of 150W(200V,0.75A), another of
> 25W(25V,1A) and another of 5W(12V,0.6A). How can I achieve this, with
> stable outputs from all converters.*

That's an input power of 200 watts and an output power of 180 watts. That's an anticipated power efficiency of 90%.

It will be tricky to achieve this because flyback converter power efficiency is more likely to be a shade under 90%. So, maybe you could just about have all three flyback converters feeding a net load power of about 175 watts. I think a total load power of 180 watts might be difficult unless you are going to compromise and make one flyback converter with multiple outputs.

The power saving for one converter (using only one controller chip) might just get you where you need to be but, there will be load regulation compromises you need to take into account.

Comment: What will be the total efficiency if each converter has 90% efficiency

Comment: It will be 90%.